# images going out of scope of parent container

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains images that are spaced around. The problem is the more images I add to that div the images that are in the first position go out of the scope of the main container div. I have added the `table-responsive` class to make the main container scrollable but the images at the first position are out of scope so I can't even scroll and see the image at the first position. How can I fix it so that the images don't go out of the scope of the parent container? To see that the first image is different delete some of the images in that container and you will see that the image is indeed there. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```css
.infoBar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  width: auto;
  height: 10%;
  max-width: 95%;
  column-gap: 25px;
  background-color: green;
}

.infoBar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none !important;
}

.infoBar .imgWrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.infoBar .imgWrap img {
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- the more .imgWrap div I add to .infoBar the images at the first position goes out of scope of .info bar and can even scroll back to it-->

<div class="table-responsive infoBar" id="infoBar">
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/1900x800"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is messing with your css, I would advise you to read carefully the doc about each class and what they do before using it.

With css only you can achieve what you're trying to do (if I understood correctly):

- as many images as you want
- all images at given size in the container
- horizontal scroll
- space between each images

```css
.infoBar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 95%;
  height: 160px;
  margin: auto;
  column-gap: 25px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.infoBar .imgWrap {
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.infoBar .imgWrap img {
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- the more .imgWrap div I add to .infoBar the images at the first position goes out of scope of .info bar and can even scroll back to it-->

<div class="infoBar" id="infoBar">
  <div class="imgWrap">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/1900x800">
  </div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
  <div class="imgWrap"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just replicated it with no bootstrap on my machine. The error still persists.

Comment: @seriously that is why I also gave you a piece of code that solves your problem. Isn't it what you want to achieve?

Comment: That's my bad didn't notice you made changes to the CSS thought the problem was bootstrap only. Thanks for your help.